# $\mu_R(m)\geq \dim R$ where $\mu_R(m)=\operatorname{embdim}R$.

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

> Let ($R,m,k$) be a noetherian local ring. Show that $\mu_R(m)\geq \dim R$ where $\mu_R(m)=\operatorname{embdim}R$.

It results by Krull's  Principal Ideal Theorem but I don't know how.

Principal Ideal Theorem: If $R$ is a noetherian ring and $I=(a_1,...,a_n)$ then $\mathrm{ht}(P)\leq n$ for any minimal prime ideal $P$ that contains $I$.

Comment: And then the result is immediate with $I=m$.

Comment: @MooS If $I=m$ and $m=(a_1,...,a_n)$ then $ht(m)\leq n$ because there is not prime that contains $m$.  $\mu_R(m)=n$ and $dim R= ht(m)$?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: @PregatireMatematica I'd say that "$m=(a_1,\dots,a_n)\implies m$ minimal over $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$" instead of "there is no prime that contains $m$". Then, by PIT, $\mathrm{ht}(m)\le n$ and you are done.